# Passing custom parameter from GRUB to the OS

Tags: shell-script, debian, grub, parameter

My program, wich is bash scripts, runs in a custom ISO with Debian.

I want a GRUB menuentry that passes a parameter from GRUB to the OS, a debugging flag, so I can test the program, and at the same time have a non debugging option, without the need of change the code.

For example, in Clonezilla you have several parameters like:

```
ocsdaemon_on="ssh"
```

which starts a ssh server.

I would put in my GRUB the parameter`debug` or other custom word, then in my program

```
DEBUG=<flag>
```

Is this possible? How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your parameter is not overlapping with any existing parameter, and just add it to the kernel command line. See the list in Linux kernel documentation here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

(`debug` is not a good choice for your program: it is already in use to enable kernel debugging.)

Then have your program read `/proc/cmdline` and look for it. That's basically all there's to it.